# Dependency injection in component's constructor

Tags: angular

I am very new in Angular and doing currently a tutorial to learn it.

I faced an issue and I wonder if someone could help me to see clear.

It is about dependency injection and creating services.

As an exercise, I needed to creat two services and inject them in another components to make them usable.

As it was taught, the dependency injection can happen in the given components's contructor in the following way:

```
constructor(private counterService: CounterService) {}
```

But in the another case it caused an error (**this constructor is not compatible with angular dependency injection**) and I need to google it and found this method:

```
constructor(@Inject(UserService) private userService) {}
```

Can someone please explain me, what's the difference between the both? The two services are located in the same folder structures. I have Angular version 9.

Thank you!

---

```
export class CounterService  {
  inactiveToActiveCount: number = 0;
  activeToInactiveCount: number = 0;

  increaseActiveToInactiveCounter() {
    this.activeToInactiveCount = this.activeToInactiveCount +1;
    console.log("Active to inactive: " + this.activeToInactiveCount);
  }

  increaseInactiveToActiveCounter() {
    this.inactiveToActiveCount = this.inactiveToActiveCount +1;
    console.log("Inactive to active: " + this.inactiveToActiveCount);
  }

}
```

---

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CounterService } from './counter.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  activeUsers = ['Max', 'Anna'];
  inactiveUsers = ['Chris', 'Manu'];

  constructor(private counterService: CounterService) {
    //
  }

  setToInactive(id: number) {
      this.inactiveUsers.push(this.activeUsers[id]);
      this.activeUsers.splice(id, 1);
      this.counterService.increaseActiveToInactiveCounter();
  }

  setToActive(id: number) {
      this.activeUsers.push(this.inactiveUsers[id]);
      this.inactiveUsers.splice(id, 1);
      this.counterService.increaseInactiveToActiveCounter();
  }
}
```

---

And I use them in this component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../common/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-active-users',
  templateUrl: './active-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./active-users.component.css']
})
export class ActiveUsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users: string[];

  constructor(@Inject(UserService) private userService) {
    //
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users = this.userService.activeUsers;
  }

  onSetToInactive(id: number) {
    this.userService.setToInactive(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: In angular9 all classes that uses dependency injection must have an angular class-level decorator @Injectable().

Comment: Can you please share your userservice and counterservice as well?

Comment: @ArunMohan i edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Angular 9, the new compiler and runtime instructions are used by default instead of the older compiler View Engine. Because of this, the following requirement is added in angular.

> Add an @Injectable decorator to anything you plan to provide or
>   inject.

Before angular 9 what you wrote was valid. But now, userService has a reference of counterService which inturn is injected into the component. So @Inject is required as counter service doesn't have @Injectable added.

Injecting service into another service doesn't have this requirement unless you are extending from another service.

https://angular.io/guide/ivy-compatibility-examples

You can check this link for understanding the issues and fixes recommended by the team during migration because v8 is still popular.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help!